# Mongoose query date range

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am storing dates in my mongo DB database like so

```
date: new Date()
```

Here is the field on the model

```
date: {type: Date, required: true},
```

It stores successfully and looks like this in DB `2020-09-14T15:28:19.462+00:00`

I then want to query documents between two dates like so

```
router.put('/filter',  (req, res, next) =>{
      //console.log(req.body.dateOne.year)
      //console.log(req.body.dateTwo.year)
      var d = new Date(2020, 09, 1);

      var endd = new Date(2020, 09, 30);

        History.find({"date":  {$gte: d, $lte: endd}}).then(documents =>{
        
        if (documents.length >= 1){

        res.status(200).json({
            message: "Got History",
            posts: documents
        });
        } else{
            res.status(404).json({
                message: "Nothing matches",
             
            });
        }

        });
  
  });
```

It always returns no documents, i've looked through similar stack overflow questions and others mentioned that it's because date is storing time, so tried adding time to dates also like so

```
var d = new Date(2020, 09, 1, 01, 00, 00, 00);
```

But still no luck.

Is there anyway to do this with just the javascript date object? or will I need to use something like https://date-fns.org/?

Also if I change start date to 2019 and not 2020 it finds documents? Not sure why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with :

```
var d = new Date(2020, 8, 1);
var endd = new Date(2020, 8, 30);
```

In `Date()` month argument starts counting at 0 not 1.

Comment: Throws hands up in the air in disbelief! Of course, so simple now. Thank you Alexis!

Comment: It's the function that is counter-intuitive. Months start at 0, but days starts at 1